# Attaching a Rotated Rectangular body to a Sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, sprite

In a game I am programming in Cocos2D and Box2D, I have a sprite that is in the shape of a hill, and I am trying to attach a body to it so it can respond to physics.  My idea is to use a rotated rectangle shape so that it aligns with the slope, but I need to be able to move the sprite so that the body stays appropriately lined up.  I can make the body and sprite work together in the case of a circle, but I can't figure out how to make it work for the case of the rotated rectangle.  Could someone explain the code to do this?

Comment: use physics editor to create fixture for irregular shape.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree to user1634707. CocosBuilder will be one potential choice.